# Cant read properties of Object in meteor 's iron router's route

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to pass object in data context in route.
I am trying to read JavaScript object(which holds the business logic) . If i send the object as such , then i can read it's properties in template. But if i try to send a custom object by reading some of it's properties . Then I am getting error that it can not read properties of same object.

```
this.route('updateBook/' ,
        {
        path:'/updateBook',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    data : function(){
                var Book = Books.findOne({hasFinished:true});

  var UpdateBookObject ={};
    UpdateBookObject.currentPage = Book.currentPage;
    UpdateBookObject.name = Book.name;  
    UpdateBookObject.author = Book.author;
    UpdateBookObject.img = Book.img;
    UpdateBookObject.numOfPages = Book.numOfPages;
    UpdateBookObject.dateStarted = Book.dateStarted;
    UpdateBookObject.dateToFinish = Book.dateToFinish;
    UpdateBookObject.percentage = (UpdateBookObject.currentPage/UpdateBookObject.numOfPages).toFixed(2);
    UpdateBookObject.pagesRemaining = UpdateBookObject.numOfPages - UpdateBookObject.currentPage;
    var finishMoment = moment(UpdateBookObject.dateToFinish,"DD-MM-YYYY");
    var startMoment = moment(UpdateBookObject.dateStarted,"DD-MM-YYYY");
  UpdateBookObject.perDayToRead = finishMoment.diff(startMoment,'days');
  return UpdateBookObject;                      
            }


        });
```

Comment: `UpdateBookObject.currentPage = Book.currentPage` is commented out, but `UpdateBookObject.currentPage` is used later in the function. Is that a typo?

Comment: @DavidWeldon-hi yes, a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure it's because `UpdateBookObject` is returning before all of those properties are added to it. Why don't you return the `Book` variable you declared (which you said works) and then use a template helper to make the calculations?

```
Templates.updateBook.helpers({
  updatedBook: function() {
    //return data here
   }
});
```

And register global template helpers to do your date parsing for you using moment, this is how I do it for timestamps:

**Global Template Helper**:

```
Template.registerHelper("dateAndTime", function(date) {
  if(date)
    return moment(date).format('l LT');
}); //returns formatted Date and Localized Time, e.g. 2/22/2015 12:30PM.
```

**Spacebars in Template**:

```
{{dateAndTime dateStarted}} //where createdAt is the field in the document
```

You can also use global template helpers instead of standard ones to do percentage calculations, and just pass the arguments from the Book object in with the Spacebars syntax in your templates.

Comment: @rashad-Nasir- See this is another way to do it , i dont want retrieve data at client side , i want to show only specific data at client, so can you tell me way in which i could pass modified and object before sending to client using data function of iron router?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues using the data function in iron:router, if I wanted to send over an "updated" objected based on a Mongo query. But you do realize you're still retrieving the data on the client, right? Is routes.js file not located in your lib folder? If you're worried about extra data in your Books document being shipped to client, limit the fields: `Collection.findOne({_id: id}, {fields: {fieldNameYouWant: 1, fieldTwo: 1}});`, and also restrict the fields in your publish function too.